# make the comment(in the rails guide exmple) editable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am learning rails by following the rails 3 guide.

The blog application have ran now,however I want to make the comment editable,and make the update ,create form both in the post show page. so I make the following modifiation:

post.show.htm.erb:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.commenter %></td>
    <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post,comment) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_comment_path(@post,comment), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>

#here,I can not set the form_for property.
<%= form_for([@post,@comment],:url=>post_comment_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controller controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts/1/comments/1/edit
  def edit
    #render json: params
    @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments=Comment.all
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    render "/posts/show"
  end

  #other action omitted

  def show
    # I donot know what to do here
  end
end
```

However I can not access the link:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1
```

I get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
```

In fact,as you can see I have the show action in CommentController.

And,I wonder why it will access the comments#show action?

This is my routes:

```
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
       home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                       home#index
             root        /                                           home#index
```

The `/posts/:id` will trigger `posts#show`. why `comments#show`?

Answer (score 0):

if u need to edit the post, then add

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to some_path and return
  end
  render 'edit' #error
end
```

the form for edit should send a PUT request to the server. rails maps the url and the request ( like GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) using the routes file to the controller actions.

here

```
PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
```

the request is PUT, controller is PostsController and the action is update.

also,

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
```

u need to pass the http request from the form if its POST/PUT/DELETE.
u can do so for 'edit'

```
<%= form_for([@post,@comment],:url=>post_comment_path, :method => :put) do |f| %>
```

maps to the show request for PostsController. the format is html bydefault. for more info, have a detailed look at the server log.